# Ubuntu 20.04 can't start mysql server

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, lts

I did release-upgrade and after this upgrade I have problems with my mysql server.
My server looks on place and it is running, but actually is not:

```
systemctl status mysql.service

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2020-07-01 14:01:37 EEST; 377ms ago
     Process: 4546 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 4554 (mysqld)
    Status: "Server startup in progress"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 6840)
    Memory: 125.5M
    CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
         └─4554 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jul 01 14:01:37 microserver systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

After running following command:

```
netstat -an|grep LIST|grep 3306
```

nothing listen here.

```
cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf 
[mysqld]
```

## * Basic Settings

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

When I try to start mysql server I have this error:

```
root@microserver:~# service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

ps ax|grep mysql
9716 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld
9744 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

When I try to connect:

```
ps ax|grep mysql
9716 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld
9744 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I did pure uninstallation and clearing everything and install again and still can't run the service.

Comment: looks like AppArmor might be blocking the startup.
I got a similar error when I checked `sudo journalctl -xe` got 
`AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock" pid=XXXX comm="mysqld"...`

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to find out why it is not running, check those logs as the error states:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
sudo journalctl -xe
```

Comment: Those are as useful as Microsoft error codes

Comment: I had a similar issue, found out by running `journalctl -xe` that AppArmor was blocking the process from starting